# How to do a multipart upload direclty from bytes, not from file on file system

Tags: go

How to do a multipart upload direclty from bytes, not from file on harddisk
All examples I see are working with files

I have binary data stored in variable name wav, how would I attached this data as the upload

```
body := &bytes.Buffer{}
writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
part, _ := writer.CreateFormFile("file", "audio.wav")
io.Copy(part, bytes.NewReader(wav))
writer.Close()

r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", requestURL, body)
r.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
r.SetBasicAuth("apikey", token)
client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(r)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

log.Println(resp)
```

Comment: The code in the question uploads directly from bytes in slice wav.  Please describe the problem you are experiencing in more detail.

Comment: "`part, _ := ...`  ... `r, _ := ...` " You're not doing yourself any favors ignoring errors.  Remember that Go doesn't raise exceptions or anything.  The error values returned are the only way to verify the statements are succeeding.